# How to delete a disabled gist on GitHub?

Tags: github, gist

I forked someone's gist, but it got unavailable in github due to DMCA takedown.

Is there any possible to delete this gist?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Isn't there a `Delete` button? Show a screenshot of that page.

Comment: No, there isn't. So I am lost.

Comment: Did you contact [GitHub Support](https://github.com/contact)?